# Can I reload a page form Service Worker (or Secondary Thread)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have a functional progressive web app. In it to upload data I'm first caching it in `IndexDB` and then uploading it and if the upload is successful delete the data from `IndexDB`. Now, I want to reload the page once the data is deleted. Is there any way to achieve this outside the main thread(ie. form service worker)?

**NOTE:**`window` object is not accessible in service worker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to communicate first with your page over the postMessage function, then you can access window and reload the page. Here you can find a good description:

http://craig-russell.co.uk/2016/01/29/service-worker-messaging.html#.WgxuSmjWzIU